# Loop or function to parse a list of XML data in R

Tags: r, function, loops, apply, lapply

I am looking for a loop or function to improve my current process on parsing XML data (I have to parse 10 of them)

My current process is

```
library（xml2, tidyverse)

data1 <- read_xml("http://wayback.archive-it.org/7993/20170406200517/https://www.fda.gov/DataSets/Recalls/2009-2011/RecallsDataSet2009-2011.xml")
data2 <- read_xml("http://wayback.archive-it.org/7993/20170405004549/https://www.fda.gov/DataSets/Recalls/2012-2014/RecallsDataSet2012-2014.xml")

df_brand <- data %>% 
  xml_find_all("//BRAND_NAME") %>% 
  xml_text()

df_product_description <- data %>% 
  xml_find_all("//PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION") %>% 
  xml_text()

df_reason <- data %>% 
  xml_find_all("//REASON") %>% 
  xml_text()

df_company <- data %>% 
  xml_find_all("//COMPANY") %>% 
  xml_text()

df_company_link <- data %>% 
  xml_find_all("//COMPANY_RELEASE_LINK") %>% 
  xml_text()

# Combine all into a dataframe one by one
abc <- data.frame(sapply(ls(pattern="^df"), get))
efg <- data.frame(sapply(ls(pattern="^df"), get))
```

Any way to get this done with a loop or function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Please note that the `library(xml2, tidyverse)` doesn't really import the `tidyverse` package. You'll have to do two separate calls to the library function)

Are you asking how to run a list of xpaths into your `data1` structure and combine the outputs into one dataframe?

If you enumerate your xpaths into a vector:

```
xpaths <- c('//PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION', '//BRAND_NAME')
```

You could then just run the following in base R:

```
x <- do.call(cbind, 
             lapply(xpaths, function(xpath) xml_text(xml_find_all(data1, xpath))))

head(x)
     [,1]              [,2]                                                                      
[1,] "Sprouts"         "Let&#39;s Grow Healthy Together!, Green Valley Food Corp., Broccosprouts"
[2,] "cheese"          "Edelweiss Creamery"                                                      
[3,] "Cheese"          "Brennan&#39;s Cellars"                                                   
[4,] "Sparkling Cider" "Martinelli&#39;s Gold Medal"                                             
[5,] "Night Cream"     "Organique by Himalaya"                                                   
[6,] "Cheese"          "Fromagerie Marie KadÃ¨"
```

Alternatively, if you want to run the same logic as above on a list of data sets, you can do as follows:

```
# bash your data frames into a list
# df_list <- list(data1, data2, ...)
x <- do.call(rbind, 
             lapply(df_list, function(data) 
                               do.call(cbind, 
                                       lapply(xpaths, 
                                              function(xpath) xml_text(xml_find_all(data, xpath))))))
```

Note that the first `do.call` is doing a rowbind of the dataframes that ensue from invoking the xpaths on each of the underlying XML data structures.

Comment: Many thank @user2474226! The `do.call` is new to me but it looks super useful.